# 1 minute difference in almost identical PostgreSQL queries?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have Rails application with the ability to filter records by state_code. I noticed that when i pass 'CA' as search term i get my results almost instantly. If i will pass 'AZ' for example it will take more than a minute though.

I don't have any ideas why so?

Below is query explains from psql:
Fast one:

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
   accounts.id
 FROM "accounts"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "addresses"
   ON "addresses"."addressable_id" = "accounts"."id"
   AND "addresses"."address_type" = 'mailing'
   AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = 'Account'
 WHERE "accounts"."organization_id" = 16
 AND (addresses.state_code IN ('CA'))
 ORDER BY accounts.name DESC;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=4941.94..4941.94 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=74.810..74.969 rows=821 loops=1)
   Sort Key: accounts.name
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 75kB
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.46..4941.93 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=70.044..73.148 rows=821 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (addresses.addressable_id = accounts.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on addresses  (cost=0.00..4911.93 rows=6806 width=4) (actual time=0.027..65.547 rows=15244 loops=1)
               Filter: (((address_type)::text = 'mailing'::text) AND ((addressable_type)::text = 'Account'::text) AND ((state_code)::text = 'CA'::text))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 129688
         ->  Hash  (cost=4.45..4.45 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=2.037..2.037 rows=1775 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 87kB
               ->  Index Scan using organization_id_index on accounts  (cost=0.29..4.45 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.018..1.318 rows=1775 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (organization_id = 16)
 Planning time: 0.565 ms
 Execution time: 75.224 ms
(14 rows)
```

Slow one:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
  accounts.id
FROM "accounts"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "addresses"
  ON "addresses"."addressable_id" = "accounts"."id"
  AND "addresses"."address_type" = 'mailing'
  AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = 'Account'
WHERE "accounts"."organization_id" = 16
AND (addresses.state_code IN ('NV'))
ORDER BY accounts.name DESC;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=4917.27..4917.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=97091.270..97091.277 rows=25 loops=1)
   Sort Key: accounts.name
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..4917.26 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=844.250..97091.083 rows=25 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (accounts.id = addresses.addressable_id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 915875
         ->  Index Scan using organization_id_index on accounts  (cost=0.29..4.45 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.017..10.315 rows=1775 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (organization_id = 16)
         ->  Seq Scan on addresses  (cost=0.00..4911.93 rows=70 width=4) (actual time=0.110..54.521 rows=516 loops=1775)
               Filter: (((address_type)::text = 'mailing'::text) AND ((addressable_type)::text = 'Account'::text) AND ((state_code)::text = 'NV'::text))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 144416
 Planning time: 0.308 ms
 Execution time: 97091.325 ms
(13 rows)
```

Slow one result is 25 rows, fast one is 821 rows, which is even more confusing.

Comment: How many rows start with 'C' and how many rows start with 'A'? Can you show us your query as well?

Comment: @LajosArpad Edited my question. I have more records with 'C' than with 'A'.
It's also not only 'AZ' the list is much bigger, it's almost only 'CA' that working properly, which is strange to me.

Comment: Petya, that's interesting. One would expect searches for California for be slower than searches for Arizona. However, here things are happening in a different manner. We can exclude order by as a cause, since the number of results is almost identical in the two cases. I wonder whether the selection clause makes it slower. Can you test with selecting a single, small column in both cases? If you do that, does the behavior change?

Comment: @LajosArpad right? Just removed big portion from query and left only things that actually matter, this time i also used NV for slow query instead of AZ to show that it's not only AZ.

Comment: @LajosArpad do you have an idea why in the EXPLAIN of slow request NESTED LOOP being used, while on fast one it's replaced by HASH JOIN? i think that's the reason, i just doesn't see where it's coming from

Comment: Petya, this is actually a big clue. Since almost all values are CA and both NV and AZ are slower, we can safely assume that the where clause is having a hard time filtering out rare elements. What happens if you use address.state_code = 'CA' instead of the IN operator? I guess that not finding the element in the set might be making the query slower. Also, to optimize, I would migrate that condition into the on of the join and I would add an index to address.state_code as well.

Comment: That is a pretty good guess about the manifestation of the problem, but since I was not among those who implemented the RDBMS, unfortunately I lack information to answer you that. It might well be that under the hood frequently queried terms are optimized, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: Moved this condition under join and changed it to '=' instead of 'IN', the result is the same. Do you think it's a good idea to have index on such text field? I'm not sure it's going to help to be honest, looks like the issue is in other place.

Comment: I just ran 'VACUUM ANALYZE' command and now everything works smoothly. Thanks for your help and hints, really helpful!

Comment: Petya, I am happy you managed to solve your problem. I would like to kindly ask you to answer your question with your findings. It will really help others who have similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `VACUUM ANALYZE` command from psql command line.